# How to make a succinct test case?

Tags: unit-testing

So I have a function for assigning relationship between Manager and Worker.
With the following requirement. There are three roles to be logged in as (Admin, Manager and Worker).

1. At all times if manager or worker is disabled - throw error("Disabled")
2. Assigned worker cannot be added - throw error("Owned")
3. Admin can add any relationship for any manager to any worker while adhering to 1. and 2. rule.
4. Manager can only add worker to himself while adhering to 1. and 2. rule.
5. Worker cannot add anything.

This is quite a simple requirement but when I am outlining on what to test I am boggled down with so many possible test case to ensure complete coverage until it feels redundant. For example,

**As Admin**

- assign unowned manager to unowned worker – success
- assign unowned manager to owned worker – fail
- assign owned manager to unowned worker – success
- assign owned manager to owned worker – fail

  ---
- assign unowned manager(disabled) to unowned worker – fail
- assign unowned manager(disabled) to owned worker – fail
- assign owned manager(disabled) to unowned worker – fail
- assign owned manager(disabled) to owned worker – fail

  ---
- assign unowned manager to unowned worker(disabled) – fail
- assign unowned manager to owned worker(disabled) – fail
- assign owned manager to unowned worker(disabled) – fail
- assign owned manager to owned worker(disabled) – fail

  ---
- assign unowned manager(disabled) to unowned worker(disabled) – fail
- assign unowned manager(disabled) to owned worker(disabled) – fail
- assign owned manager(disabled) to unowned worker(disabled) – fail
- assign owned manager(disabled) to owned worker(disabled) – fail

**As Manager**

- assign unowned manager(self) to unowned worker – success
- assign unowned manager(self) to owned worker – fail
- assign owned manager(self) to unowned worker – success
- assign owned manager(self) to owned worker – fail
- assign unowned manager(other) to unowned worker – fail
- assign unowned manager(other) to owned worker – fail
- assign owned manager(other) to unowned worker – fail
- assign owned manager(other) to owned worker – fail

  ---
- assign unowned manager(self disabled) to unowned worker – fail
- assign unowned manager(self disabled) to owned worker – fail
- assign owned manager(self disabled) to unowned worker – fail
- assign owned manager(self disabled) to owned worker – fail
- assign unowned manager(other disabled) to unowned worker – fail
- assign unowned manager(other disabled) to owned worker – fail
- assign owned manager(other disabled) to unowned worker – fail
- assign owned manager(other disabled) to owned worker – fail

  ---
- assign unowned manager(self) to unowned worker(disabled) – fail
- assign unowned manager(self) to owned worker(disabled) – fail
- assign owned manager(self) to unowned worker(disabled) – fail
- assign owned manager(self) to owned worker(disabled) – fail
- assign unowned manager(other) to unowned worker(disabled) – fail
- assign unowned manager(other) to owned worker(disabled) – fail
- assign owned manager(other) to unowned worker(disabled) – fail
- assign owned manager(other) to owned worker(disabled) – fail

  ---
- assign unowned manager(self disabled) to unowned worker(disabled) – fail
- assign unowned manager(self disabled) to owned worker(disabled) – fail
- assign owned manager(self disabled) to unowned worker(disabled) – fail
- assign owned manager(self disabled) to owned worker(disabled) – fail
- assign unowned manager(other disabled) to unowned worker(disabled) – fail
- assign unowned manager(other disabled) to owned worker(disabled) – fail
- assign owned manager(other disabled) to unowned worker(disabled) – fail
- assign owned manager(other disabled) to owned worker(disabled) – fail

You can see where it is going with testing as Worker login. I hope this shows the general idea of how verbose the test cases are. What do developer generally do in such case to make a concrete and succinct test cases?

```
function addUser(login, managerId, workerId) {
   if (login.accountType === "Worker" || login.accountType === "Manager" && login.Id !== managerId) {
          throw utils.permissionError;
   }
   try {
      const manager = database.one(Users.getActiveManagerById, managerId); // if no manager return method will throw error
      const worker = database.one(Users.getActiveWorkerById, workerId); // if no worker return method will throw error
      const relationship = database.one(UserRelationships.addUserRelationship, managerId, workerId);
      return "Success"
   } catch (e) { 
      return "Fail"
   }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Expanding on honey's answer,

Am I wrong to think that tests should be written without looking at function implementation? If you look at the function's code would the test be biased towards the implementation?

I am just thinking whether it is possible that the badly written code passed all the tests despite the lack of coverage. I want to have tests that given any function, the tests ensure that passing mean the function works completely.

For example in the point

**testAdminAuthority**: You no longer need to be considerate of rule 1 & 2.

A badly written code would be

```
if (login.accountType !== "Admin") { //test disable }
```

Then in this case the rule 1 and 2 didn't get a chance to kick in and admin can assign disabled manager or disabled worker.

If I list out all the permutations, this way no matter how the function is written, it ensures that all cases are considered?

Many other point can be intentionally hindered but still pass.
It's not that I want to intentionally break any code/logic. I am about to do mass refactoring of the code and I want to have tests to cover the functionality once the refactors are done.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question completely but I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what unit-testing is. Understanding it would probably simply things 10X. But first let me try to better understand your question: 1. "At all times if manager or worker is disabled" say I'm an admin and I login...then I must have an option of clicking on Manager/worker and if I don't the app should fail?! 2. "assigned workers cannot be added" you mean if person X is already assigned now he can't be assigned again? And if he is able to be assigned then the test should fail?

Comment: @Honey sorry for the confusion. So this is a backend service testing. I am assuming all client is malicious and can submit any request to server. So if he request the manager to be assigned to an owned worker. The server will response with fail message. Or if he tries to submit and matched a disabled manager with someone then the failed message is returned. Hope this clears things up?

Comment: The way you write the question is confusing...after you wrote: testAdminAuthority... I'm not sure if the code snippet is test code or the actual code...Which test are you are you talking about? test3? In test3 you only test what's related to that *unit* then in test1,2 you test *other* things...it's how you do unit-testing. I still can't see what's wrong though. Rule 1,2 will get called and won't pass the tests...if you do them right, test 1,2,3,4,5 and any other test should not be dependent on one another.

Comment: @Honey sorry for the confusion yet again! Yes I was talking about test3. I was illustrating how it might be possible to bypass the test due to a badly written code. The code in the snippet is an example of possible badly written ACTUAL code. I am not sure how verbose test1 and test2 should be, but it seems that test1 and test2 does not deal with admin rights. So assuming the user login as Admin, we can bypass test1 and test2 easily with the badly written code snippet. All I am saying is that it is possible to pass all the tests even though it is not 100% correct in term of functionaily?

Comment: in testDisabledusers from my answer...I said: you should assert if the right error is not thrown when you choose from a disabled. <-- This also applies to Admins. So you have it covered don't you?

Comment: @Honey, I think I am a little lost :P If I manage to make Admin add disabled users successfully, it also will not throw right error? In this case I am still passed the test because "right error was not thrown"?

Comment: In your **production** code...you should have a *disablederror* ( you can name it anything you like) thrown for anyone attempting to add a disabled user. In your **test** code you just have to make an attempt to add a disabled user and assert if that *disablederror* is not thrown.

Comment: so if by any chance in your production code...you don't have the *disableerror* then your test would fail—indicating you messed up!

Comment: Oh when you said "assert if the the right error was not thrown". "Right" in this context means "Correct"? I was confused with right with admin's rights.

Comment: hah! Yes I meant correct

Comment: @Honey, I think I start to see what is my problem now. I don't have a unique error message for each senario. All the fail message will be like "Fail". Do you think this will make the test harder to cover?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142539/discussion-between-honey-and-zanko).

Answer (score 1):

> 1. At all times if manager or worker is disabled throw  error("Disabled")
> 2. Assigned worker cannot be added - throw error("Owned")
> 3. Admin can add any relationship for any manager to any worker while adhering to 1. and 2. rule.
> 4. Manager can only add worker to himself while adhering to 1. and 2. rule.
> 5. Worker cannot add anything.

From what I understand you only need the above 5 test cases, if each of your **units** are tested right then you no longer need to test how the two units work together, that's exactly *why* it's called **unit**...testing.

Assuming you have wrote all the code needed to avoid these situations your tests would look something like:

1. **testDisabledusers:** say you have an array of disabled workers and another of disabled manager...
   if your user has chose from these...then your test would be to '**assert if the the right error was not thrown** e.g. your message would be "user is disabled, can't assign"' something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31558635/how-to-test-method-that-throws-error-in-swift-2)
2. **testAssignedWorkers:** Same logic as your test 1
3. **testAdminAuthority:** You no longer need to be considerate of rule 1 & 2, you have them already tested. Though what I actually *guess* this test is, is: only *admin* can add any manger to worker relation (other managers can only add to themselves). so to purely test if once they add a worker to a manager does it actually get assigned or not—If they were ever trying to assign a disabled manager/worker or assigned worker then your unit test 1 & 2 would kick in...no need to re-cover that in this test.
4. **testManagerRestriction:** if your manager has chose from another manager...then your test would be to '**assert if the the right error was not thrown** e.g. your message would be "wo wo wo wait a minute, you're not his manager, can't do it!"' something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31558635/how-to-test-method-that-throws-error-in-swift-2) again.
5. **testWorkerRestriction:** same as above, just that it should its appropriate–related method.

(remember to give your tests an appropriate name, perhaps you can come up with better names)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Perhaps you can address my concerns. I just feel that this does not cover all the cases. I will update my question to reflect this.

Comment: @Zanko please explain which scenario this does not address. Where it does not cover...

Comment: I apologize for lack of description I was busy. I have updated my concerns. It sounds a bit outrageous but I hope it address my point! Thank you so much though for taking your time to answer.